# как я могу выводить в консоль все запросы к API?

Tags: api, rest, backend, nestjs

**main.ts**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule,
    {
      logger: console,
    }
  );
  await app.listen(4000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: не совсем понятно о чем речь. речь о запросах к стороннему апи или запросы к приложению?

Comment: типа логи запроса сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключите его как middleware: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]